# VUE + WEBPACK couldn't find #app

Tags: webpack, vue.js, webpack-dev-server

I started my dev server normally with `npm run serve` but after load the `localhost:8080` comes this error

[image: error code]

Can someone help me, I think it's a problem with webpack but I don't know.

Comment: Can you attach your code, webpack config..? It would be easier to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I have found that error in my `router.js` file which causing the problem. 
There was two routes with the equal path

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an infinite loop. It could be in your Vue code, and it could be in a regex. Are you using regex? Or is there anything weird in your route definitions? Did this ever build? Try commenting out parts of your code to see if you can get the rest to build.